# Express API Call returning Text/HTML

Tags: javascript, express

Currently creating an API with Express.js and trying to call it via Javascript on a plain page.

This is the express.js code:

```
// Display all accounts
exports.get_accounts = function(req, res) {
    // res.send("Front end not implemented: List all accounts");
    var params = {
        TableName: "HouseAccounts",
    }
    docClient.scan(params, onScan);
    function onScan(err, data) {
       if (err) {
           console.error("Unable to read: ", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
       }
       else {
           res.header("Content-Type",'application/json');
           return data.Items;
       }
    }
}
```

And this is the call from javascript

```
var $api = jQuery.noConflict();
const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";

$api(document).ready(function() {
  fetch(proxyurl + "myURL/accounts")
  .then(res => console.log(res));
});
```

If I log `res` to the console, I receive:
`Response {type: "cors", url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://039f1b…aab34.vfs.cloud9.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/accounts", redirected: false, status: 499, ok: false, …}`

This does not contain the data from my database. I know the route itself is working because if I visit the localhost page I can see the data being displayed. If I do `console.log(res.json())` I receive `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`.

In the network tab, it's showing that the data is coming over as text/html. I'm not sure why the data is not coming over as JSON.

Comment: What response are you getting?

Comment: Are you implementing a client side routing?

Comment: @CristianTraìna No I am not

Comment: @SLaks On the server side if I pull up the express page I am getting `[{"PortalID":2,"Name":"Test Account"},{"PortalID":1,"Name":"Test Account"}]` which is what I expect from my database

Comment: How are you serving the client webapp? I guess the problem is here

Comment: What response do you see in the Network Tab?

Comment: @CristianTraìna it's served through a CMS. I am just putting javascript on a plain html page

Comment: @slaks seems like it is an HTML file in the response...it is too long for me to post.. here is an excerpt

`<div class="subtext">
                VFS connection does not exist
            </div>

            <div class="error_content info" id="project-access-msg">
                <p>AWS Cloud9 can't get you to your requested environment. Here are some suggestions on how to figure out what's going on:
                    <div class="baseList">`

Comment: @slaks Seems like I am having some cross domain issue with AWS cloud9 because it is being run on localhost I think